# How to print a specific attribute of multiple objects in Python

Tags: python, object, attributes

I'm trying to iterate through a list of objects and print out a specific attribute of which they all have.

for example:

```
class egg:
    def __init__(self, spam):
        self.spam = spam

x1=egg(1)
x2=egg(2)
x3=egg(3)

eggSalad=[x1,x2,x3]
print(eggSalad[:].spam)
```

I would like to get:

```
1
2
3
```

but recieve the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'utility'
```

I understand why the error is occurring but don't understand how to achieve my goal.

What is the correct way to go about doing this?

Comment: `for egg in egg_salad: print(egg.spam)`? The class should be named `Egg`.

Comment: Lists don't have a `spam` attribute, even if you copy them with `[:]` (which is completely pointless here). Use a loop.

Comment: `[obj.spam for obj in eggSalad]`

Comment: Thank you! couldn't locate that question when searching for the subject